# Apache JCI FilesystemAlterationMonitor processes changes for existing folder contents on startup

Tags: java, filesystemwatcher, apache-commons-jci

I am using Apache JCI's FAM (FileAlterationMonitor) in a Java OSGi Service to monitor and handle changes in the FileSystem. Everything seems to be working fairly well except whenever I start the Service (which starts the FAM using the code below), FAM picks up on ALL the changes that exist in the directory.

Currently I am watching /tmp
/tmp includes a subtree: /tmp/foo/bar/cat/dog

Everytime I start the service and which starts FAM, it reports DirectoryCreate events for:

```
/tmp/foo
/tmp/foo/bar
/tmp/foo/bar/cat
/tmp/foo/bar/cat/dog
```

Even if no changes have been made to any part of that subtree.

Code run on service activation:

```
File watchFolder = new File("/tmp"); 
watchFolder.mkdirs();

fam = new FilesystemAlterationMonitor();
fam.setInterval(1000);
fam.addListener(watchFolder, listener);
fam.start();
// I've already tried adding:
listener.waitForFirstCheck();
```

Listener example:

```
private FileChangeListener listener = new FileChangeListener() {
    public void onDirectoryChange(File pDir) { System.out.println(pDir.getAbsolutePath()); }
    public void onDirectoryCreate(File pDir) { System.out.println(pDir.getAbsolutePath()); }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's one very annoying feature of JCI. When monitoring is started, it will notify you of all the files and directories it finds with calls to `onXxxCreate()`. I think you have the following options

- After starting the monitoring, wait for some time (couple of seconds) in your `FileChangeListener` callback implementation before you actually process the events coming from JCI. That's what I did in a project and it works fairly well, although there is the possibility that you miss an actual file creation that just happens within the "grace period"
- Take the sources of JCI and modify them to use two new event methods `onDirectoryFound(File)`and `onFileFound(File)` that will only be fired when files and directories are found on startup of the monitoring
- Take a look at `java.nio.file.WatchService` that comes with Java 7. IMO the best option, as it uses native methods internally in order to be notified of changes by the OS, instead of starting a thread and checking periodically. With JCI, you may get delays in the range of several seconds until changes are propagated to your callbacks

Comment: Unfortunately the platform im building on doesnt support JDK 7 so thats out.

I ended up using the grace period strategy and that works pretty well. I am look into the second option just for my own edification.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about WatchService. It is not intuitive and there are issues with it when trying to see if it can detect that the folder it is monitoring is deleted or changed. I would stay far away from it. I have worked with Watcher but prefer Apache IO much more. I believe Camel uses it as well.